# Balancing molecular and net ionic equations for reactions

Tags: physical-chemistry, stoichiometry

**Source:**'Chemistry: The Central Science 11th edition' by Brown. Ch.4, 4.53:
**Question:**

> Write balanced molecular and net ionic equations for the reactions of:
>
> 1. chromium with hydrobromic acid;
> 2. tin with hydrochloric acid.

**My attempts:**

1. $\ce{ Cr(s) + 2HBr(aq) →CrBr2(aq)~ or~ CrBr3(aq)? + H2(g)}$

   I got the left part of the reaction correct, but I can't figure out what charge chromium should have because it can have either $\ce{+2}$ charge or $\ce{+3}$ charge when it ionizes.  The answer says that it should be $\ce{CrBr2}$, but why can't it be $\ce{CrBr3}$?
2. same thing for this option. Why can't $\ce{SnCl4}$ can be an answer?